# How to add new groups in Proxmox.py dynamic inventory

Tags: python-3.x, regex, ansible, ansible-inventory, proxmox

I use this inventory script:
[xezpeleta/Ansible-Proxmox-inventory](https://github.com/xezpeleta/Ansible-Proxmox-inventory/blob/master/proxmox.py).

It works fine but now I want to add a new group based on `proxmox_name` field value.

I found the lines to duplicate in the script.

I duplicate this:

```py
            # Create group 'running'
            # so you can: --limit 'running'
            status = results['_meta']['hostvars'][vm]['proxmox_status']
            if status == 'running':
                if 'running' not in results:
                    results['running'] = {
                        'hosts': []
                    }
                results['running']['hosts'] += [vm]
```

into this:

```py
            # Create group 'bddservers'
            # so you can: --limit 'bddservers'
            bddservers = results['_meta']['hostvars'][vm]['proxmox_name']
            if bddservers == 'x-xxxxx-x-Bxx':
                if '.-....-.-B..' not in results:
                    results['bddservers'] = {
                        'hosts': []
                    }
                results['bddservers']['hosts'] += [vm]
```

to create a group consisting of only BDD servers.

I want to base it on the hostname server (`proxmox_name` field) but when I try pattern `'*B*'` it doesn't work. If I replace it with a single hostname server it works, I have a group bddservers with only the hostname I set.

How can I replace the single hostame by a pattern? The naming convention is like this: `x-xxxxx-x-Bxx` when the `B` is for BDD servers only. The code is in Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without modification of the inventory script:

```yaml
- name: Add hosts to the BDD group
  add_host:
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    groups: bddservers
  when: proxmox_name is regex('.*-.*-.*-B.*')
```

Also, note that your original regex does not match the example host name you give in your question. I simplified it so you can use it to check and modify accordingly later.

Speaking of your original intention to add the hosts to the group from the script - you just need to fix the condition to something like this:

```py
import re
...
name = results['_meta']['hostvars'][vm]['proxmox_name']
  if re.fullmatch('.*-.*-.*-B.*', name):
    if 'bddservers' not in results:
      results['bddservers'] = {
        'hosts': [] 
      }
    results['bddservers']['hosts'] += [vm]
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer but this solution as the other i already find is that print only one server instead of all

Comment: Which one of the two options I offered does not work for you? Could you edit your question and add some results that the inventory script provides for your environment?

Comment: Thanks you for your quick answer
i did not test the first solution because my purpose is to create group in the python script so the second solution dos not work

Comment: @KainTaozia I fixed the logic, please check.

Comment: Works like a charm thanks you very much
PS : there is some mini typo (missed the string arguments and simple quote on hosts)
            name = results['_meta']['hostvars'][vm]['proxmox_name']
            if re.fullmatch('.*-.*-.*-B.*', name):
              if 'bddservers' not in results:
                results['bddservers'] = {
                  'hosts': [] 
                }
              results['bddservers']['hosts'] += [vm]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, was editing quickly from the phone. Fixed now